# sumar y ver resultado actualizado en la paguina

Tags: php, html

quiero saber si existe la forma de sumar los resultados de varios  en PHP y en automático se muestre el resultado en la misma pagina.

estos son mis

```html
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                               <label for="sel1">Evauación Criticidad</label>
                                 </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <select class="form-inline"  name="Criticidad">
                                    <option value= "0">0</option>
                                    <option value= "1">1</option>
                                    <option value= "3">3</option>
                                    <option value= "5">5</option>
                                    </select>    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                                 <label for="sel1">Evauación Ocurrencia</label>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-md-9">
                                 <select class="form-inline" name="Ocurrencia">
                                    <option value= "0">0</option>
                                    <option value= "1">1</option>
                                    <option value= "3">3</option>
                                    <option value= "5">5</option>
</select>    
                                  </div>
                      </div>
```

y esta es mi operación en PHP

```html
<div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                                 <label for="sel1">Evauación Valor del Riesgo</label>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-md-9">
                                     <?php
                                     is_numeric($_Criticidad = $_POST["Criticidad"]);
                                     is_numeric($_Ocurrencia = $_POST["Ocurrencia"]);
                                     is_numeric($_Reaccion = $_POST["Reaccion"]);
                                     
                                     $_suma = $_Criticidad * $_Ocurrencia * $_Reaccion;
                                     
                                     ?>
                                 <label for="sel1"><?php echo $_suma ?></label>
                                 </div>
                                 </div>
```

Comment: Puedes ser un poco más específico ? Que te muestra ahora? qué error hay?

Comment: lo estoy realizando con PHP pero no me lo actualiza en automático el resultado de la suma.

Comment: Te refieres a que lo actualize sin recargar la pagina?

Comment: Tu variable `$_suma` esta multiplicando como nos pones el código, ahí no sumando

Comment: si asi es. yo selecciono el valos 5 en Criticidad y 3 en Ocurrencia y que me aparezca 15 en el resultado si requerir algún boton.

Comment: pero es el mismo escenario, solo requiero que el resultado se de sin algún boton, solo al seleccionar la cantidad

Comment: Si se puede hacer en PHP pero necesitarias usar Ajax.  Lo mas facil en tu caso seria hacerlo en javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que seria mas facil hacerlo en javascript.  Seria algo asi:

```js
function mult() {
  var cri = document.getElementById("Criticidad").value;
  var ocu = document.getElementById("Ocurrencia").value;
  document.getElementById("sel1").innerHTML = cri * ocu; 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
         <label for="sel1">Evauación Criticidad</label>
           </div>
              <div class="col-md-9">
              <select class="form-inline"  name="Criticidad" id="Criticidad">
              <option value= "0">0</option>
              <option value= "1">1</option>
              <option value= "3">3</option>
              <option value= "5">5</option>
              </select>    
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
           <label for="sel1">Evauación Ocurrencia</label>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-9">
           <select class="form-inline" name="Ocurrencia" id="Ocurrencia" onChange="mult()">
              <option value= "0">0</option>
              <option value= "1">1</option>
              <option value= "3">3</option>
              <option value= "5">5</option>
           </select>    
     </div>
</div>
<label id="sel1"></label>
```